# Spring Boot Health Report on HTML Page

Tags: json, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot application. I am using actuator for health monitoring. I know that we can get health by using http://localhost:8080/health which returns you JSON with status of application, disk space and DB status.

I want to show this health report in well formatted on HTML page means on GUI format. I don't want to use Spring Boot Admin UI. Is there is any way where I can use this json in HTML or thymeleaf themplate.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Docs mentions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health):

> Health information is collected from all `HealthIndicator` beans defined in your `ApplicationContext`. Spring Boot includes a number of auto-configured `HealthIndicators` and you can also write your own.

So you can autowire `List<HealthIndicator>` into your controller and inject that data into your Theameleaf template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you have any sample code for this.